# Json to temp table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to convert below JSON to SQL **#temp** table.

```
{

  "Person":

  {

     "Name": "John",

     "age": 25,

     "Address":

     {
        "streetAddress":"21 2nd St New York",

        "postal":"10021"
     },

     "Numbers":

     {

        "home":"212 555-1234",

        "fax":"646 555-4567"

     }

  }

}
```

**Output:**

```
+-------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| Person/Name | Person/age | Person/Address/streetAddress | Person/Address/postal | Person/Numbers/home | Person/Numbers/fax |
+-------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| John        |         25 | 21 2nd St New York           |                 10021 | 212 555-1234        | 646 555-4567       |
+-------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

**Questions:**

Is there any build-in function to do this work ?

Is there any per-defined CLR available ?

Can we do this with a table valued function ?

> Currently I'm using this online [Converter](http://konklone.io/json/) to convert as
>   CSV  then uploading it to Database. This one works fine till now , But
>   i need to save time by directly uploading to database.

Comment: Native support will be available from [SQL Server 2016](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx)

Comment: I need a Common Language Runtime  ?

Answer (score 0):

for this problem i haved use this solution.
IMHO i think is the best solution for the version of SQL SERVER before the 2016.

i don't post you the code, because is little bit long.

I post you the link of the function, the example and the discussion about it.

[Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server by Phil Factor](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

I hope this is hopefully for you.

Comment: This should be comment [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Natively, there is no support for MS-SQL 2012. You will have to use [CLR](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/).

Well, you can always use a huge not-nice JSON parser, that may not be 100% working. One of them for example [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: Can you create a CLR for me ?